# SQL SERVER 2008 - Select avg min rate for a particular room

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
rate     | id_room  | id_plan  | date                                                  
500.00   | 25       | 2        |2016-05-03 
700.00   | 26       | 3        |2016-05-03
900.00   | 25       | 4        |2016-05-03
800.00   | 26       | 5        |2016-05-03
600.00   | 25       | 2        |2016-05-04
700.00   | 26       | 3        |2016-05-04
900.00   | 25       | 4        |2016-05-04
1000.00  | 26       | 5        |2016-05-04
```

trying to select min avg rates for particular room, suppose min rate for id_room 25 is 500 on 2016-05-03 and 600 on 2016-05-04, so i should get min avg rate 550 for id_room 25... like that min avg rate 700 for id_room 26..
I tried with Row_Number(), but getting exception.. (in Sql server 2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves two levels of aggregation, if I understand correctly:  once by room and date and the second by room:

```
select id_room, avg(rate)
from (select id_room, date, min(rate) as minrate
      from t
      group by id_room, date
     ) rd
group by id_room;
```

However, I don't fully understand the question, because roooms seems to be booked only once on a given date, so the minimum on a given date *is* the rate.  Perhaps your data is not representative of what you really need.

Comment: I have to show the average rates if the customer books room for 2 days

Comment: the above works fine if i am not select id_plan, if i select id_plan then it returns all the avg rate of a plans for a particular id_room. I want only one min avg rate plan of a particular room